# Stream problems on Safari

Tags: iphone, html, safari

http://silver.co.uk/rla

I have problems with the above page. Setup information is on the page.

1. **It does not play on iPhone** (iOS 5). The file plays if downloaded to iPhone first but does not stream from the page. The play button does nothing.
2. **It only plays after loading the video on Safari on Windows**. i.e. it doesn't stream as soon as you click on the play button but wait to load the video. Then it plays. This doesn't happen on Safari for MacOS.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Riz